# My function to find anagrams returns me None

Tags: python

I'm coding a function in python, which is supposed to return the differents anagrams of a word. But when I test it, the function returns me none. Could you help me please ?
Thank you very much ;)

My code :

```
import random

def factorial(number):
  result = 1

  for i in range(1, number + 1):
    result *= i
  
  return result


def find_anagrams(word):
  letters = []
  anagramms = []
  
  for letter in word:
    letters.append(letter)
  
  possibilities = factorial(len(letters))
  tries = 0
  
  while tries < possibilities:
    random.shuffle(letters)
    new_word = letters[0]
    
    for i in range(1, len(letters)):
      new_word += letters[i]
    
    if new_word not in anagramms:
      anagramms.append(new_word)  
      tries += 1


print(find_anagrams("hello"))
```

Comment: add the return statement `return anagramms` to you function

Comment: also better use permutaions than random shuffle

Comment: Does this answer your question? [producing all the anagrams from a string python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989502/producing-all-the-anagrams-from-a-string-python)

Comment: Oh thank you I am so dumb ^^ x)

Comment: @Serge 's suggestion is absolutely critical but not enough. Your code gets stuck in an infinite loop. You're incrementing `tries` inside an `if` that may never be executed until the `while` condition becomes false.
Having said that, your code doesn't even give the certainty that all possible anagrams will be generated at each execution.

Comment: as I mentioned in the second comment, `itertool.permutations` solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Few challenges in your code/style

1. Missing `return statement` in your `find_anagrams`. Your code is doing compute but your are not passing it down your print functions
2. Using `random.shuffle` is not correct. Random sometimes does repeat. Is it correct?
3. What happens to your code if the input has duplicate chars ? Lot of redundant work.

I would suggest you to look into `Depth First Search (DFS)` or `Recursion` or `Backtracking` algorithm here. With out one of these, your code won't be able to perform all required operations.

In case you have a dictionary of words, using a graph algo DFS along with `Tries` data structure would be more cost efficient.